# como Guardar imágenes en una carpeta de recursos en c# y llamarla mediante su URL en SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Estoy desarrollando una App Local que Guarda imágenes de perfil introducidas por el usuario, el tema es que no quiero agregar directamente las imágenes a la DB por que tengo entendido que es una mala practica, aparte planeo agregar complejidad mas adelante ya que en una sola inserción el usuario podría subir 8 o mas imágenes, lo que busco es lo siguiente:

- Guardar la imagen introducida por el Usuario en una Carpeta de recursos
- Guardar la URL en la DB
- Acceder a la imagen en el picture box `User_Pic`

**boton agregar imagen al picture box**

```
private void Btn_Agregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog getimage = new OpenFileDialog();
            DialogResult result = getimage.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Pic_Profile.Image = Image.FromFile(getimage.FileName);
            }
            
        }
```

**Registro en la DB desde c#**

```
public void CrearUsuarios
            (
        string usuario,
        string Nombre,
        string Apellido,
        bool sexo,
        int somatotipo,
        int edad,
       float peso,
       float altura,
       string ProfilePic)
        {
            Command.Connection = Conexion.AbrirConexion();
            Command.CommandText = "NewUser";
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginName", usuario);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", Nombre);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Apellido);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SexIdent", sexo);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomatoTypeIdent", somatotipo);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", edad);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", peso);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", altura);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfilePic", ProfilePic);
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Command.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        private void Btn_NewUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float Peso = float.Parse(txtPeso.Text);
            float Altura = float.Parse(TxtAltura.Text);
            Math.Round(Peso, 2);
            Math.Round(Altura, 2);
             try
             {
                 register.CrearUsuarios(
                     TxtUsuario.Text,
                     TxtNombre.Text,
                     TxtApellido.Text,
                     Convert.ToBoolean(cmbsexos.SelectedValue),
                     Convert.ToInt32(cmbSomato.SelectedValue),
                     Convert.ToInt32(TxtEdad.Text),
                     Peso,
                     Altura,
                     Convert.ToString(Pic_Profile.ImageLocation));

                 UserModel user = new UserModel();


                 MessageBox.Show("Registro Exitoso");
                 this.Close();

                 Login login = new Login();
                 login.Show();
             }
             catch (Exception error)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Error " + error.Message);
             }
```

*Procedimiento almacenado*

```
USE [FitnessApp]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[NewUser]    Script Date: 09/01/2021 14:14:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[NewUser]

@LoginName nvarchar(100),
@FirstName nvarchar(100),
@LastName nvarchar(100),
@SexIdent bit,
@SomatotypeIdent int,
@age int,
@Height float,
@Weight float,
@ProfilePic nvarchar(500)
as
declare @UserID int
insert into Users values (@LoginName,@FirstName,@LastName,@SexIdent,@SomatotypeIdent,@age, GetDate(),@ProfilePic)



set @UserID = @@IDENTITY

insert into UserHeight values (@UserID,@Height, GetDate())

insert into UserWeight values (@UserID,@Weight, GetDate())
```

Hasta ahora me encontré con el inconveniente de que no me esta guardando el url por que me manda este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Almacenar imágenes o blobs en general en SQL Server no se recomendaba porque causaba problemas de rendimiento, pero a partir de la versión 2008 tenemos disponible [FILESTREAM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) que resuelve ese problema. El enfoque que planteas puede causar problemas de mantenimiento en la medida que crece el volumen de datos y por eso recomiendo evaluar la opción del FILESTREAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

espero te ayude, al hacer click en este boton llama al metodo `prodimg();`

```
 /****************************************
         MEDTODO GUARDAR IMAGNES DE LOS EMPLEADOS 
         EN LA CARPETA CREADA POSTERIORMENTE
       *****************************************/
        private void imgProducto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        prodimg();
    }
```

se manda a llamar el metodo  `prodimg()` de crear una carpeta dentro de los recursos del programa que estas creando, si no existe la carpeta la crea y te manda un mensaje. lo que tiene comentario lo puedes usar como tu quieras. `Filter` solo puedes ver imagenes con la extencion PNG Y JPG. Si todo esta bien coloca la imagen en el picturebox la centra.

```
  private void prodimg()
        {
            crearCarpetasProductos();

            //MIME TYPES FILTRAR QUE SOLO ACEPTE 2 TIPOS DE EXTENCION
            openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Imagenes JPG,PNG|*.jpg;*.png";
            
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            
            //OBTENEMOS LA EXTENCION DE LA IMAGEN 
            //string extimg = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            //EL CODIGO DEL PRODUCTO SERA EL NOMBRE Y LE AGREGAMOS LA EXTENCION DE LA IMAGEN
            //nombimg = (txtcodigoProducto.Text) + extimg;
            //rutaimagtxt.Text = extimg;
            

            if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imgProducto.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                imgProducto.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
                imgProducto.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            }
}
```

con este se crea la carpeta si no existe la crea y si exite pues ya existe.

```
/****************************************
              MEDTODO CREAR CARPETA IMAGEN PRODUCTOS
            *****************************************/
            private void crearCarpetasProductos()
            {
                //VARIBLE QUE CONTENDRA EL NOMBRE DE LA CARPETA PRODUCTOS
                string imgProductos = Application.StartupPath + @"\imgProductos";
    
                try
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(imgProductos) )//&& Directory.Exists(imgProductos))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Se creara un directorio para almacenar las imagenes de los pruductos");
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(imgProductos);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un Error :\n " + ex);
                }
            }
```

ok te explico con el picturebox en las propiedades ay un boton se llama Eventos ahi le di el evento de dobleclick para que se abriera el openfiledialog para buscar la imagen que se colocara en el picturebox, ahora en las propiedades del picture box le agrege una imagen pero desde las propiedades y esa imagen se queda guardada en la carpeta recurso, entonces si el usuario no seleciona una imagen por defecto tendra esa.

ahora con este boton se guarda la imagen donde se le asigne la direccion y sino se selecciona ninguna imagen se queda con la que le colocastes desde las propiedades del picturebox.

ahi tienes todo lo que necesitas buscar entre las carpetas
elegir la imagen segun el filtro que quieres
puedes obtener el nombre de la imagen con su extencion
solamente mandas a guardar a la base de datos el nombre y la direccion de donde
se encuentras la concatenes colocandola en un string como se te haga mas facil

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveFileDialog1  = new SaveFileDialog();
            
             //SOLO ACEPTA IMAGENES PNG Y JPG
             saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Imagenes JPG,PNG|*.jpg;*.png";
            
             //DIRECTORIO DONDE SE GUARDARA LAS IMAGENES DE LOS PRODUCTOS
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\SistFerr\Presentacion\bin\Debug\imgProductos";
            //saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalizedResources);
             

            //EN LA VENTANA DE GUARDAR SE COLOCA EL CODIGO DEL PRODUCTOL 
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = txtcodigoProducto.Text;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                //imgProducto.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                //if (File.Exists(rutaimagtxt.Text))
                //{
                    //imgProducto.Image.Dispose();
                    //imgProducto.Image = null;   
                    imgProducto.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                //}

                rutaimagtxt.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

            }
            else
            {
                imgProducto.Image = Presentacion.Properties.Resources.fogoprod;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hasta ahora solo he podido agregar al picturebox la imagen y obtener la ruta, tu código me parece interesante pero necesitare un poco de asesoría, tienes tiempo para chatear?

Comment: ok me avisas se claro con lo  q vallas a preguntar. saludos

Comment: algun medio de contacto que quieras usar?

Comment: algun chat o correo al que pueda escribirte?

Comment: Mamdame tu correo para contactarte. Saludos

Comment: ganinox@gmail.com , espero tu mensaje!